# Corosync on cloud servers

Tags: corosync

I have two Oracle Linux 7 servers on cloud and I want to use Corosync. Servers are on the same cloud network (not LAN), but they only have one nic. Here are the conf files.

Server A:

```
totem {
        version: 2

        secauth: off
        transport: udpu

        crypto_cipher: none
        crypto_hash: none

        interface {
                member {
                        memberaddr: x.y.z.i
                }
                member {
                        memberaddr: x.y.z.j
                }
                ringnumber: 0
                bindnetaddr: x.y.z.i
                mcastport: 5405
                ttl: 1
        }
}

logging {
        fileline: off
        to_stderr: no
        to_logfile: yes
        logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
        to_syslog: yes
        debug: off
        timestamp: on
        logger_subsys {
                subsys: QUORUM
                debug: off
        }
}

quorum {
        #provider: corosync_votequorum
}
```

Server B:

```
totem {
        version: 2

        secauth: off
        transport: udpu

        crypto_cipher: none
        crypto_hash: none

        interface {
                member {
                        memberaddr: x.y.z.i
                }
                member {
                        memberaddr: x.y.z.j
                }
                ringnumber: 0
                bindnetaddr: x.y.z.j
                mcastport: 5405
                ttl: 1
        }
}

logging {
        fileline: off
        to_stderr: no
        to_logfile: yes
        logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
        to_syslog: yes
        debug: off
        timestamp: on
        logger_subsys {
                subsys: QUORUM
                debug: off
        }
}

quorum {
        #provider: corosync_votequorum
}
```

When I start Corosync services on both servers, I see that they do not join each other but in the logs of server A there are recurring log entries every two seconds:

```
Jun 08 04:22:48 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (x.y.z.i:20544) was formed. Members
Jun 08 04:22:48 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Jun 08 04:22:49 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (x.y.z.i:20548) was formed. Members
Jun 08 04:22:49 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Jun 08 04:22:50 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (x.y.z.i:20552) was formed. Members
Jun 08 04:22:50 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Jun 08 04:22:52 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (x.y.z.i:20556) was formed. Members
Jun 08 04:22:52 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Jun 08 04:22:53 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (x.y.z.i:20560) was formed. Members
Jun 08 04:22:53 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Jun 08 04:22:55 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (x.y.z.i:20564) was formed. Members
Jun 08 04:22:55 [17856] serverA corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
```

And here are the "corosync-cmapctl |grep member" outputs:

Server A:

```
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1489420110.config_version (u64) = 0
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1489420110.ip (str) = r(0) ip(x.y.z.i)
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1489420110.join_count (u32) = 1
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1489420110.status (str) = joined
totem.interface.0.member.0 (str) = x.y.z.j
totem.interface.0.member.1 (str) = x.y.z.i
```

Server B:

```
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1489420107.config_version (u64) = 0
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1489420107.ip (str) = r(0) ip(x.y.z.j)
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1489420107.join_count (u32) = 1
runtime.totem.pg.mrp.srp.members.1489420107.status (str) = joined
totem.interface.0.member.0 (str) = x.y.z.j
totem.interface.0.member.1 (str) = x.y.z.i
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you copied the corosync cluster key which is under /etc/corosync/authkey ?

Comment: secauth is off, so I thought I didn't need to do this. Now that you said, I tried and it didn't work. Here is what I did: corosync-keygen -l and then copy /etc/corosync/authkey to server B.

Comment: try to use tcpdump for capture the udp traffic on corosync port

Comment: I see that there is UDP traffic between the servers on port 5405.

Comment: in bindnetaddr are you using a network mask or an ip address?

Comment: I use the IP addresses of the servers. Which are reachable from the Internet. They are of form x.y.z.i and x.y.z.j. Subnet mask is 26 bits by the way.

Comment: bindnetaddr
              This  specifies  the network address the corosync executive should bind to.  For example, if the local interface is 192.168.5.92 with netmask 255.255.255.0, you can find the address to use there with "ip r s" command
              set bindnetaddr to 192.168.5.0.  If the local interface is 192.168.5.92 with netmask 255.255.255.192, set bindnetaddr to 192.168.5.64, and so forth.

Comment: @Hakan You must use a private IP not the public IP

Comment: @FedericoSierra You are right, I defined private IPs and it worked! If you could put this in an answer I'll accept it. Thanks. c4f4t0r Thanks for your help as well, it was quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a private IP not the public IP

Answer (score 0):

corosync uses multicast network communication which is blocked by some cloud providers, AWS to name one.

http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/

> Q. Does Amazon VPC support multicast or broadcast?
>
> No

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I changed the configuration to use Unicast.

Comment: You may want to update your question to reflect the change to unicast.

Comment: I mean I changed it before I posted it as a question. I added "transport: udpu" to the conf file and it's present in the question.